# Sublime Text - ignore tab settings for specific file types

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to have Sublime Text 3 ignore the `"translate_tabs_to_spaces"` settings for specific file types (namely `.tsv`, `.csv` and `.txt`)?

Additionally, is it possible to have ST3 not translate tabs when *pasting*? 
eg, I might copy text from a .tsv and paste it into a new file.  I want to preserve the tabs.  Right now, this involves changing my preferences, pasting, then changing back those preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unsure about the pasting, but you can set syntax specific settings by going to `Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User`. You can also check out https://github.com/randy3k/SyntaxMgr

Comment: SyntaxMgr is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!